# Why am I getting this error “one or more unbound namespace prefixes” for Sitemap.xml

Tags: xhtml, sitemap, google-search-console, xml-sitemap, bing-webmaster-tools

I have submitted my sitemap.xml into google webmaster tools. We found error such as "The XML Sitemap cannot be parsed because it contains one or more unbound namespace prefixes. For example, this error is generated when  is found in a Sitemap without prior xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"."

My sitemap url: http://www.cadservicesindia.com/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this first line in your XML file is mis-formatted. It seems to have the url pasted twice, likely by mistake:

```
<urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9             http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

try this line instead:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

Comment: I edited the answer slightly, based on reading this post: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en

Comment: The sitemap at cadservicesindia.com has not been corrected yet, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: Six years later and I had the same issue, the URL was pasted twice as you said and I didn't notice till I read your answer, and I had to change the attribute to `xmlns`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
Try adding this at the top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```